# Uniform convergence of $ x(1-x)^n $ in [0,1]

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f_n(x)=x(1-x)^n$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Find the pointwise limit $f $ of the sequence and verify if it is uniformly convergent to $ f$ at this interval.

**My attempt:**

Since $x \in [0,1]$, then $0 \leq (1-x)^n \leq 1. $

If $x = 0$ or $x=1, f_n(x) = 0$ and $\lim f_n(x) = 0$

If $ 0 < x < 1, $ then, since $0 < (1-x) < 1, \lim (1-x)^n =0 $ and so does $ \lim f_n(x).$

Then, we have that $f(x)=0. $ Now, I want to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to this function on the given interval. We can observe that the funcion $|f_n(x) - f(x)| $ is decreasing at the interval $\big(\frac{1}{n+1},1\big) $and increasing at $\big(0,\frac{1}{n+1}\big) $ , since the derivative of this function is

$$(1-x)^n - nx(1-x)^{n-1} = -(1-x)^{n-1}(nx+x-1)$$

Now, if I take I as the union of both intervals, and prove the limit of the modulus function is zero, I am done. We just need to calculate the $f_n$ in all the extremes and apply the sandwich theorem to do this. But i am worry that I am not being rigorous with the interval extremes. Does it looks correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "prove the limit of the modulus function is zero": it's not clear to me what you mean here. Do you mean "prove that the limit of the maximum value of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ is zero"? If so (and if you can prove it) then your proof looks good to me.

Comment: If I prove that $\lim|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$ for all $x$ at the given interval, $n=1,2,...$, then I am proving that the limit of the maximum also equals zero. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: The maximum of each $f_n$ is at $x = \frac{1}{n+1}$. And since $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$, it is, indeed, the maximum at $[0,1], right?

Comment: Yes, because the derivative is zero only at $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_n$ are continuous, then $f_n$ converges uniformly to the zero function if and only if $M_n \to 0$, where $M_n = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|$. You have already found $\arg \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|$, it is $\frac{1}{n+1}$. So substitute and see what your maximum is.

Comment: Thanks! It is a much better approach then using squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Giiovanna Usually you can't find the max explicitly in order to use this procedure, but when you can it is probably the best tool for the job.