# Show that $n x (1-x)^n < 1$ for any $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Why $n x (1-x)^n < 1$ for any $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Looks at its derivative, as is done in the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/941942/

Comment: If you put "\$" around your $\LaTeX$, it will render as math. I did it for you.  Hope I got the math right.  Anyway, like this:  "\$ $\LaTeX$ \$".  Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried doing this by induction on $n$?

Answer (score 10):

By AM-GM inequality: $nx(1-x)^n \leq \left(\dfrac{nx + n(1-x)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}< 1^{n+1} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

By the change of variable $x=\dfrac t{t+1}$, with $t>0$, the inequation becomes
$$nt<(1+t)^{n+1},$$
which is obviously true by the binomial theorem.

Comment: By the same argument you have the stronger $(n+1)x(1-x)^n<1$ and $(1+nx)(1-x)^n<1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider the function $$f(x)=n x (1-x)^n $$ Its derivative write $$f'(x)=-n (1-x)^{n-1} (n x+x-1)$$ which cancels if $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and then $$f\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\lt1^{n+1}=1$$

**Edit after Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's comment**

I forgot to show that this was a maximum and this has to be done using the second derivative test. What can be shown is that $$f''\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)=-n^n (n+1)^{2-n}$$ which is negative; so, it is a maximum.

Comment: Well, you need some extra work to establish the fact that you found a maximum.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez. I totally agree ! I edit. Thanks

Comment: The derivative has the same sign as $-((n+1)x-1)$, so it's positive for $x<1/(n+1)$. No second derivative needed.

Comment: @egreg. You are totally right !! Cheers :-)